# Getting A segmentation Fault in sorting a linked list

Tags: c, sorting

everytime I run this loop , I get a segmentation fault in the second iteration of the loop .

```
node *new,*new1;

new=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
new1=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
new = start->next;

for(;new->next != NULL;new = new->next)
{
    for(new1=new->next;new1 != NULL;new1=new1->next)
    {   //printf("LOOP\n");
        if(new->data > new1->data)   
        {
            printf("\n Swapping - new:%d and  new1:%d\n",new->data,new1->data); 
            temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp1 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp1 = new->next;
            temp = new1->next;
            new->next = temp;
            printf("Temp var : %d\n",temp->data);
            printf("Temp1 var : %d\n",temp1->data);
            new1->next = new;

            new1 = new;
            new = temp1;
            printf("After swapping , new:%d and new1 : %d\n",new->data,new1->data);
            //        free(temp);
            //       free(temp1);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I give a list to it - eg. 4,1,9,6
   it only swaps 4 and 1 , when it is the iteration to swap 9 and 6 ,  it shows and segmentation fault .

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes like this. That will at least help you locate where in your code the crash happens. The next step is to step through your code, line by line, in a debugger to figure out *why* it might happen. Most likely there's a pointer you don't update correctly, or doesn't initialize at all.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you leak memory (the two `malloc`s for `temp` and `temp1`)

Comment: Talking about pointers, `new = start->next;` will lead to a *memory leak*. You first make `new` point to some memory, then you make it point to some *other* memory, losing the original pointer. I also recommend you read [this old question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), about casting the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Your sort routine should not allocate anything, so the code you have now just makes zero sense and should be scrapped immediately.

Comment: An observation:  The two calls to `malloc` inside the `if` statement, where `temp` and `temp1` are assigned, are nothing more than memory leaks, since immediately after allocating the storage, you immediately assign other values to `temp` and `temp1`, permanently losing that storage without ever having used it.  It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Lastly, you say you get "a segmentation fault in the second iteration of *the loop*"... *Which* loop? You have two loops, which one is on its second iteration when the crash happens?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: What are start and start-next initialized to?

Answer (score 0):

After executing `temp = new1->next;`, `temp` could be `NULL` if `new1` was the last node of the list. While `temp` is `NULL`, it would raise a segment error when you visit it's field in this line `printf("Temp var : %d\n",temp->data);`